# Применение css в styleSheet

Tags: c++, css, qt

Сделал градиент кнопки в фотошеп, сгенерировал css. Получил вот такой код:

```
.Прямоугольник_1 {
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(255,110,2) 0%, rgb(255,255,0) 50%, rgb(255,182,0) 
 74%, rgb(255,109,0) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(255,110,2) 0%, rgb(255,255,0) 50%, 
 rgb(255,182,0) 7    4%, rgb(255,109,0) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(255,110,2) 0%, rgb(255,255,0) 50%, rgb(255,182,0) 
 74%, rgb(255,109,0) 100%);
  position: absolute;
 left: 490px;
 top: 76px;
 width: 116px;
 height: 38px;
 z-index: 7;
}
```

Скопировав его в styleSheet кнопки. Подумал должно заработать. Но не увидел изменений. Ошибок тоже нет. Можно применять css из фотошоп в qt 4.7.8? Если да то как это сделать?

Comment: Стили применять можно, но вам нужно правильно указывать для какого элемента применяете `.Прямоугольник_1` это не корректный класс для элемента в целом и стилей вообще )

Comment: qss поддерживает ограниченное подмножество атрибутов и функций css. см https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html . Поэтому копировать можно не все.